# Android AndEngine problem with touch events

Tags: android, andengine, touch-event

I'm learning andEngine and trying to make a simple game based on some examples. My problem is that the game stops in some random moments and I can only use back button ;/ I used logcat and found problem, here's log:

> /release-keys'
>
> I/DEBUG   ( 2656): pid: 4918, tid:
>   4926  >>> com.homework.mygame <<<
>   I/DEBUG   ( 2656): signal 11
>   (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault
>   addr 3f8191d 4 I/DEBUG   ( 2656):  r0
>   00000000  r1 00000000  r2 3f800000  r3
>   000191d4 I/DEBUG   ( 2656):  r4
>   00140a30  r5 00149978  r6 449d9b18  r7
>   44dbe008 I/DEBUG   ( 2656):  r8
>   449d9b6c  r9 43707d58  10 43707d40  fp
>   449d9ed8
>
> I/DEBUG   ( 2656):  ip 00000000  sp
>   449d9b00  lr 8062eeb8  pc 806189b8 
>   cpsr 600 00010 I/AndEngine( 4918):
>   org.anddev.andengine.input.touch.TouchEvent$TouchEventPool was exhausted, with 3 item
>   not yet recycled. Allocated 1 more.
>   I/AndEngine( 4918):
>   org.anddev.andengine.util.pool.PoolUpdateHandler$1 was exhausted, with
>   3 item not yet recycled. Allocated 1
>   more . I/AndEngine( 4918):
>   org.anddev.andengine.input.touch.TouchEvent$TouchEventPool was exhausted, with 4 item
>   not yet recycled. Allocated 1 more.
>   I/AndEngine( 4918):
>   org.anddev.andengine.util.pool.PoolUpdateHandler$1 was exhausted, with
>   4 item not yet recycled. Allocated 1
>   more . I/AndEngine( 4918):
>   org.anddev.andengine.input.touch.TouchEvent$TouchEventPool was exhausted, with 5 item
>   not yet recycled. Allocated 1 more.
>   I/AndEngine( 4918):
>   org.anddev.andengine.util.pool.PoolUpdateHandler$1 was exhausted, with
>   5 item not yet recycled. Allocated 1
>   more . I/AndEngine( 4918):
>   org.anddev.andengine.input.touch.TouchEvent$TouchEventPool was exhausted, with 6 item
>   not yet recycled. Allocated 1 more.
>   I/AndEngine( 4918):
>   org.anddev.andengine.util.pool.PoolUpdateHandler$1 was exhausted, with
>   6 item not yet recycled. Allocated 1
>   more . I/AndEngine( 4918):
>   org.anddev.andengine.input.touch.TouchEvent$TouchEventPool was exhausted, with 7 item
>   not yet recycled. Allocated 1 more.
>   I/AndEngine( 4918):
>   org.anddev.andengine.util.pool.PoolUpdateHandler$1 was exhausted, with
>   7 item not yet recycled. Allocated 1
>   more . I/AndEngine( 4918):
>   org.anddev.andengine.input.touch.TouchEvent$TouchEventPool was exhausted, with 8 item
>   not yet recycled. Allocated 1 more.
>   I/AndEngine( 4918):
>   org.anddev.andengine.util.pool.PoolUpdateHandler$1 was exhausted, with
>   8 item not yet recycled. Allocated 1
>   more . I/AndEngine( 4918):
>   org.anddev.andengine.input.touch.TouchEvent$TouchEventPool was exhausted, with 9 item
>   not yet recycled. Allocated 1 more.
>   I/AndEngine( 4918):
>   org.anddev.andengine.util.pool.PoolUpdateHandler$1 was exhausted, with
>   9 item not yet recycled. Allocated 1
>   more . D/dalvikvm(  929): Cronos
>   GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 166K, 55% free
>   2686K/5895K, ex ternal 905K/987K,
>   paused 268ms I/AndEngine( 4918):
>   org.anddev.andengine.input.touch.TouchEvent$TouchEventPool was exhausted, with 10 item
>   not yet recycled. Allocated 1 more.
>   I/AndEngine( 4918):
>   org.anddev.andengine.util.pool.PoolUpdateHandler$1 was exhausted, with
>   10 item not yet recycled. Allocated 1
>   mor e. I/AndEngine( 4918):
>   org.anddev.andengine.input.touch.TouchEvent$TouchEventPool was exhausted, with 11 item
>   not yet recycled. Allocated 1 more.
>   I/AndEngine( 4918):
>   org.anddev.andengine.util.pool.PoolUpdateHandler$1 was exhausted, with
>   11 item not yet recycled. Allocated 1
>   mor e. I/AndEngine( 4918):
>   org.anddev.andengine.input.touch.TouchEvent$TouchEventPool was exhausted, with 12 item
>   not yet recycled. Allocated 1 more.
>   I/AndEngine( 4918):
>   org.anddev.andengine.util.pool.PoolUpdateHandler$1 was exhausted, with
>   12 item not yet recycled. Allocated 1
>   mor e. I/AndEngine( 4918):
>   org.anddev.andengine.input.touch.TouchEvent$TouchEventPool was exhausted, with 13 item
>   not yet recycled. Allocated 1 more.
>   I/AndEngine( 4918):
>   org.anddev.andengine.util.pool.PoolUpdateHandler$1 was exhausted, with
>   13 item not yet recycled. Allocated 1
>   mor e. I/AndEngine( 4918):
>   org.anddev.andengine.input.touch.TouchEvent$TouchEventPool was exhausted, with 14 item
>   not yet recycled. Allocated 1 more.
>   I/AndEngine( 4918):
>   org.anddev.andengine.util.pool.PoolUpdateHandler$1 was exhausted, with
>   14 item not yet recycled. Allocated 1
>   mor e. I/AndEngine( 4918):
>   org.anddev.andengine.input.touch.TouchEvent$TouchEventPool was exhausted, with 15 item
>   not yet recycled. Allocated 1 more.
>   I/AndEngine( 4918):
>   org.anddev.andengine.util.pool.PoolUpdateHandler$1 was exhausted, with
>   15 item not yet recycled. Allocated 1
>   mor e. I/AndEngine( 4918):
>   org.anddev.andengine.input.touch.TouchEvent$TouchEventPool was exhausted, with 16 item
>   not yet recycled. Allocated 1 more.
>   I/AndEngine( 4918):
>   org.anddev.andengine.util.pool.PoolUpdateHandler$1 was exhausted, with
>   16 item not yet recycled. Allocated 1
>   mor e. I/AndEngine( 4918):
>   org.anddev.andengine.input.touch.TouchEvent$TouchEventPool was exhausted, with 17 item
>   not yet recycled. Allocated 1 more.
>   I/AndEngine( 4918):
>   org.anddev.andengine.util.pool.PoolUpdateHandler$1 was exhausted, with
>   17 item not yet recycled. Allocated 1
>   mor e. I/AndEngine( 4918):
>   org.anddev.andengine.input.touch.TouchEvent$TouchEventPool was exhausted, with 18 item
>   not yet recycled. Allocated 1 more.
>   I/AndEngine( 4918):
>   org.anddev.andengine.util.pool.PoolUpdateHandler$1 was exhausted, with
>   18 item not yet recycled. Allocated 1
>   mor e. I/AndEngine( 4918):
>   org.anddev.andengine.input.touch.TouchEvent$TouchEventPool was exhausted, with 19 item
>   not yet recycled. Allocated 1 more.
>   I/AndEngine( 4918):
>   org.anddev.andengine.util.pool.PoolUpdateHandler$1 was exhausted, with
>   19 item not yet recycled. Allocated 1
>   mor e. I/AndEngine( 4918):
>   org.anddev.andengine.input.touch.TouchEvent$TouchEventPool was exhausted, with 20 item
>   not yet recycled. Allocated 1 more.
>   I/AndEngine( 4918):
>   org.anddev.andengine.util.pool.PoolUpdateHandler$1 was exhausted, with
>   20 item not yet recycled. Allocated 1
>   mor e. I/AndEngine( 4918):
>   org.anddev.andengine.input.touch.TouchEvent$TouchEventPool was exhausted, with 21 item
>   not yet recycled. Allocated 1 more.
>   I/AndEngine( 4918):
>   org.anddev.andengine.util.pool.PoolUpdateHandler$1 was exhausted, with
>   21 item not yet recycled. Allocated 1
>   mor e. I/AndEngine( 4918):
>   org.anddev.andengine.input.touch.TouchEvent$TouchEventPool was exhausted, with 22 item
>   not yet recycled. Allocated 1 more.
>   I/AndEngine( 4918):
>   org.anddev.andengine.util.pool.PoolUpdateHandler$1 was exhausted, with
>   22 item not yet recycled. Allocated 1
>   mor e. I/AndEngine( 4918):
>   org.anddev.andengine.input.touch.TouchEvent$TouchEventPool was exhausted, with 23 item
>   not yet recycled. Allocated 1 more.
>   I/AndEngine( 4918):
>   org.anddev.andengine.util.pool.PoolUpdateHandler$1 was exhausted, with
>   23 item not yet recycled. Allocated 1
>   mor e. I/AndEngine( 4918):
>   org.anddev.andengine.input.touch.TouchEvent$TouchEventPool was exhausted, with 24 item
>   not yet recycled. Allocated 1 more.
>   I/AndEngine( 4918):
>   org.anddev.andengine.util.pool.PoolUpdateHandler$1 was exhausted, with
>   24 item not yet recycled. Allocated 1
>   mor e. I/AndEngine( 4918):
>   org.anddev.andengine.input.touch.TouchEvent$TouchEventPool was exhausted, with 25 item
>   not yet recycled. Allocated 1 more.
>   I/AndEngine( 4918):
>   org.anddev.andengine.util.pool.PoolUpdateHandler$1 was exhausted, with
>   25 item not yet recycled. Allocated 1
>   mor e. I/AndEngine( 4918):
>   org.anddev.andengine.input.touch.TouchEvent$TouchEventPool was exhausted, with 26 item
>   not yet recycled. Allocated 1 more.
>   I/AndEngine( 4918):
>   org.anddev.andengine.util.pool.PoolUpdateHandler$1 was exhausted, with
>   26 item not yet recycled. Allocated 1
>   mor e. I/AndEngine( 4918):
>   org.anddev.andengine.input.touch.TouchEvent$TouchEventPool was exhausted, with 27 item
>   not yet recycled. Allocated 1 more.
>   I/AndEngine( 4918):
>   org.anddev.andengine.util.pool.PoolUpdateHandler$1 was exhausted, with
>   27 item not yet recycled. Allocated 1
>   mor e. D/dalvikvm(  929): Cronos
>   GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 10K, 55% free
>   2686K/5895K, ext ernal 905K/927K,
>   paused 294ms D/dalvikvm(  929): Cronos
>   GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 5K, 55% free
>   2686K/5895K, exte rnal 920K/1016K,
>   paused 135ms I/DEBUG   ( 2656):
>
> ## 00  pc 000189b8  /data/data/com.homework.mygame/lib
>
> /libandenginephysicsbox2dextension.so
>   (_ZN6b2Body13CreateFixtureEPK12b2FixtureDe
>   f) I/DEBUG   ( 2656):          #01  pc
>   0000bfbc 
>   /data/data/com.homework.mygame/lib
>   /libandenginephysicsbox2dextension.so
>   (Java_com_badlogic_gdx_physics_box2d_Body_
>   jniCreateFixture__JJFFFZSSS) I/DEBUG
>   ( 2656):          #02  pc 00011d74 
>   /system/lib/libdvm.so I/DEBUG   (
>   2656): I/DEBUG   ( 2656): code around
>   pc: I/DEBUG   ( 2656): 80618998
>   eb00595d e3500000 0a000001 e1a00004
>   I/DEBUG   ( 2656): 806189a8 ebfffd9f
>   e594205c e3a03a19 e2833f75 I/DEBUG   (
>   2656): 806189b8 e7921003 e1a00005
>   e3811001 e7821003 I/DEBUG   ( 2656):
>   806189c8 e8bd81f0 e594105c e1a00005
>   e284200c I/DEBUG   ( 2656): 806189d8
>   e2811a19 e2811f76 eb0003ae eaffffe2
>   I/DEBUG   ( 2656): I/DEBUG   ( 2656):
>   code around lr: I/DEBUG   ( 2656):
>   8062ee98 e51d0004 e12fff1e e1a0c000
>   e1a00001 I/DEBUG   ( 2656): 8062eea8
>   e1a0100c eaffffff e92d400f ebffffe1
>   I/DEBUG   ( 2656): 8062eeb8 e3500000
>   43700000 e8bd800f e52de008 I/DEBUG   (
>   2656): 8062eec8 ebfffff8 03a00001
>   13a00000 e49df008 I/DEBUG   ( 2656):
>   8062eed8 e52de008 ebfffff3 33a00001
>   23a00000 I/DEBUG   ( 2656): I/DEBUG
>   ( 2656): stack: I/DEBUG   ( 2656):
>   449d9ac0  43707d58 I/DEBUG   ( 2656): 
>   449d9ac4  43707d40 I/DEBUG   ( 2656): 
>   449d9ac8  449d9ed8 I/DEBUG   ( 2656): 
>   449d9acc  80617174 
>   /data/data/com.homework.mygame/lib/li
>   bandenginephysicsbox2dextension.so
>   I/DEBUG   ( 2656):     449d9ad0 
>   00149978 I/DEBUG   ( 2656):
>   449d9ad4  449d9b18 I/DEBUG   ( 2656): 
>   449d9ad8  0000ffff I/DEBUG   ( 2656): 
>   449d9adc  44dbe008 I/DEBUG   ( 2656): 
>   449d9ae0  00000001 I/DEBUG   ( 2656): 
>   449d9ae4  00000000 I/DEBUG   ( 2656): 
>   449d9ae8  00000000 I/DEBUG   ( 2656): 
>   449d9aec  421cf249 I/DEBUG   ( 2656): 
>   449d9af0  bf800001 I/DEBUG   ( 2656): 
>   449d9af4  8062ef1c 
>   /data/data/com.homework.mygame/lib/li
>   bandenginephysicsbox2dextension.so
>   I/DEBUG   ( 2656):     449d9af8 
>   df002777 I/DEBUG   ( 2656):
>   449d9afc  e3a070ad I/DEBUG   ( 2656):
>
> ## 00 449d9b00  ffffffff I/DEBUG   ( 2656):     449d9b04  00000000 I/DEBUG
>
> ( 2656):     449d9b08  80632718
>   I/DEBUG   ( 2656):     449d9b0c 
>   43707d84 I/DEBUG   ( 2656):
>   449d9b10  449d9b6c I/DEBUG   ( 2656): 
>   449d9b14  8060bfc0 
>   /data/data/com.homework.mygame/lib/li
>   bandenginephysicsbox2dextension.so
>   I/DEBUG   ( 2656): #01 449d9b18 
>   80632718 I/DEBUG   ( 2656):
>   449d9b1c  0016a928 I/DEBUG   ( 2656): 
>   449d9b20  00000000 I/DEBUG   ( 2656): 
>   449d9b24  00000000 I/DEBUG   ( 2656): 
>   449d9b28  00000000 I/DEBUG   ( 2656): 
>   449d9b2c  00000000 I/DEBUG   ( 2656): 
>   449d9b30  00017b00 I/DEBUG   ( 2656): 
>   449d9b34  0000ffff I/DEBUG   ( 2656): 
>   449d9b38  449d9b90 I/DEBUG   ( 2656): 
>   449d9b3c  00000003 I/DEBUG   ( 2656): 
>   449d9b40  44843052 I/DEBUG   ( 2656): 
>   449d9b44  aca11d78 
>   /system/lib/libdvm.so I/AndEngine(
>   4918):
>   org.anddev.andengine.input.touch.TouchEvent$TouchEventPool was exhausted, with 28 item
>   not yet recycled. Allocated 1 more.
>   I/AndEngine( 4918):
>   org.anddev.andengine.util.pool.PoolUpdateHandler$1 was exhausted, with
>   28 item not yet recycled. Allocated 1
>   mor e. I/AndEngine( 4918):
>   org.anddev.andengine.input.touch.TouchEvent$TouchEventPool was exhausted, with 29 item
>   not yet recycled. Allocated 1 more.
>   D/dalvikvm(  602): Cronos
>   GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 257K, 40% free
>   6266K/10311K, e xternal 1546K/1581K,
>   paused 445ms I/AndEngine( 4918):
>   org.anddev.andengine.util.pool.PoolUpdateHandler$1 was exhausted, with
>   29 item not yet recycled. Allocated 1
>   mor e. I/AndEngine( 4918):
>   org.anddev.andengine.input.touch.TouchEvent$TouchEventPool was exhausted, with 30 item
>   not yet recycled. Allocated 1 more.
>   I/AndEngine( 4918):
>   org.anddev.andengine.util.pool.PoolUpdateHandler$1 was exhausted, with
>   30 item not yet recycled. Allocated 1
>   mor e. I/AndEngine( 4918):
>   org.anddev.andengine.input.touch.TouchEvent$TouchEventPool was exhausted, with 31 item
>   not yet recycled. Allocated 1 more.
>   I/AndEngine( 4918):
>   org.anddev.andengine.util.pool.PoolUpdateHandler$1 was exhausted, with
>   31 item not yet recycled. Allocated 1
>   mor e. I/AndEngine( 4918):
>   org.anddev.andengine.input.touch.TouchEvent$TouchEventPool was exhausted, with 32 item
>   not yet recycled. Allocated 1 more.
>   I/AndEngine( 4918):
>   org.anddev.andengine.util.pool.PoolUpdateHandler$1 was exhausted, with
>   32 item not yet recycled. Allocated 1
>   mor e. D/dalvikvm(  929): Cronos
>   GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 11K, 55% free
>   2685K/5895K, ext ernal 726K/889K,
>   paused 139ms D/dalvikvm(  929): Cronos
>   GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 10K, 55% free
>   2686K/5895K, ext ernal 667K/749K,
>   paused 140ms D/dalvikvm(  929): Cronos
>   GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 5K, 55% free
>   2685K/5895K, exte rnal 920K/1016K,
>   paused 138ms D/dalvikvm(  602): Cronos
>   GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 32K, 40% free
>   6246K/10311K, ex ternal 1403K/1470K,
>   paused 343ms I/BootReceiver(  602):
>   Copying /data/tombstones/tombstone_02
>   to DropBox (SYSTEM_ TOMBSTONE)
>   E/InputDispatcher(  602): channel
>   '408f3600
>   com.homework.mygame/com.homework.myg
>   ame.com.homework.mygame (server)' ~
>   Consumer closed input channel or an
>   error oc curred.  events=0x8
>   E/InputDispatcher(  602): channel
>   '408f3600
>   com.homework.mygame/com.homework.myg
>   ame.com.homework.mygame (server)' ~
>   Channel is unrecoverably broken and
>   will be disposed! D/Zygote  (  565):
>   Process 4918 terminated by signal (11)
>   D/dalvikvm(  602): Cronos
>   GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 123K, 39% free
>   6384K/10311K, exter nal 958K/1470K,
>   paused 141ms I/dalvikvm-heap(  602):
>   Grow heap (frag case) to 9.928MB for
>   161568-byte allocat ion D/dalvikvm( 
>   602): Cronos GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 3K,
>   38% free 6538K/10503K, externa l
>   958K/1470K, paused 147ms
>   I/WindowManager(  602): WIN DEATH:
>   Window{408f3600
>   com.homework.mygame/com.homew
>   ork.mygame.com.homework.mygame
>   paused=false} D/dalvikvm(  602):
>   Cronos GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 2K, 38%
>   free 6537K/10503K, externa l
>   847K/1359K, paused 143ms
>   I/dalvikvm-heap(  602): Grow heap
>   (frag case) to 9.891MB for 80792-byte
>   allocati on D/dalvikvm(  602): Cronos
>   GC_FOR_MALLOC freed <1K, 38% free
>   6615K/10631K, extern al 847K/1359K,
>   paused 144ms D/dalvikvm(  602): Cronos
>   GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 217K, 40% free
>   6398K/10631K, exter nal 847K/1359K,
>   paused 142ms I/WindowManager(  602):
>   WIN DEATH: Window{4090fff8 SurfaceView
>   paused=false} D/gralloc (  602):
>   freeing GPU buffer at 0 D/gralloc ( 
>   602): freeing GPU buffer at 307200
>   I/ActivityManager(  602): Process
>   com.homework.mygame (pid 4918) has
>   died. W/InputManagerService(  602):
>   Got RemoteException sending
>   setActive(false) notif ication to pid
>   4918 uid 10088 D/dalvikvm(  929):
>   Cronos GC_EXPLICIT freed 9K, 55% free
>   2683K/5895K, external 4 89K/889K,
>   paused 68ms
>   V/com.mobilityflow.animatedweather.services.UpdateService$ServiceThread(
>   929): Timed alarm onReceive() started
>   at time: 2011-05-13 17:07:25.491
>   W/System.err(  929):
>   java.net.UnknownHostException:
>   www.yr.no W/System.err(  929):    at
>   java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.jav
>   a:506) W/System.err(  929):    at
>   java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.jav
>   a:294) W/System.err(  929):    at
>   java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:25
>   6) W/System.err(  929):    at
>   org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOper
>   ator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:136)
>   W/System.err(  929):    at
>   org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(Abst
>   ractPoolEntry.java:164) W/System.err( 
>   929):    at
>   org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.o
>   pen(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
>   W/System.err(  929):    at
>   org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.ex
>   ecute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:348)
>   W/System.err(  929):    at
>   org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execut
>   e(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
>   W/System.err(  929):    at
>   org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execut
>   e(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
>   W/System.err(  929):    at
>   org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execut
>   e(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
>   W/System.err(  929):    at
>   com.mobilityflow.animatedweather.weather_providers.Yr
>   Provider.loadWeatherWeek(YrProvider.java:440)
>   W/System.err(  929):    at
>   com.mobilityflow.animatedweather.weather_providers.Yr
>   Provider.providerLoadWeather(YrProvider.java:135)
>   W/System.err(  929):    at
>   com.mobilityflow.animatedweather.weather_providers.We
>   atherProvider.loadWeatherData(WeatherProvider.java:125)
>   W/System.err(  929):    at
>   com.mobilityflow.animatedweather.WebProvider$ThreadWe
>   atherLoad.run(WebProvider.java:256)

So I guess it's because on onAreaTouched function. I use it to control a player, there are 2 arrows and we can touch them to move player from left to right. Am I doing it correctly or should I do it in another way ? Here's my code:

```
 mRArrow = new Sprite(125, CAMERA_HEIGHT - 55, mRArrowTextureRegion) {
                @Override
                protected void onManagedUpdate(float pSecondsElapsed) {

                    super.onManagedUpdate(pSecondsElapsed);
                }

                @Override
                public boolean onAreaTouched(TouchEvent pSceneTouchEvent,
                        float pTouchAreaLocalX, float pTouchAreaLocalY) {


                    Body playerBody = mPhysicsWorld.getPhysicsConnectorManager()
                        .findBodyByShape(mPlayer);

                    playerBody.setTransform(new Vector2((playerBody.getPosition().x + 0.15f) ,playerBody.getPosition().y), 0);

                    return true;
                }
             };

            mLArrow = new Sprite(15, CAMERA_HEIGHT - 55, mLArrowTextureRegion) {
                @Override
                protected void onManagedUpdate(float pSecondsElapsed) {

                    super.onManagedUpdate(pSecondsElapsed);
                }

                @Override
                public boolean onAreaTouched(TouchEvent pSceneTouchEvent,
                        float pTouchAreaLocalX, float pTouchAreaLocalY) {

                    Body playerBody = mPhysicsWorld.getPhysicsConnectorManager()
                    .findBodyByShape(mPlayer);

                    playerBody.setTransform(new Vector2((playerBody.getPosition().x - 0.15f) ,playerBody.getPosition().y), 0);

                    return true;
                }
             };
```

Thanks in advance

Greg

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do not touch a Physics-"Body" inside of a TouchEvent. UI-Thread and UpdateThread hate working at the same time!

Comment: I am checking collision on IUpdateHandler onUpdate( ), just added some more objects and its allocating 183 touch events and my game lagging.

Comment: Then, how can we use a Physics body (in my case, a digital "joystick" control)? I have to touch it to move a sprite.

Comment: @Nicolas Gramlich well, I just take AndEngine over. And I account this same problem. Maybe it should be fixed in the core someday.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error and it was because I had not called scene.registerTouchArea(...). 
Hope this helps somebody.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the problem appeared when I try use

```
physicsWorld.destroyBody(fixture.getBody());
```

I avoided this line and the scene worked fine.