# Why is my game crashing with no error in the LogCat (Android)?

Tags: android, box2d, andengine

I'm using AndEngine with Box2D to make a game for the Android OS. I'm getting the strangest error and I can't, for the life of me, figure out what is causing it. It's relatively random when it happens (although not random as to where in the code it happens), but my game inevitibely crashes with only this in the LogCat:

```
    07-06 09:56:56.383: V/AndEngine(14907): org.andengine.input.touch.TouchEvent$TouchEventPool<TouchEvent> was exhausted, with 1 item not yet recycled. Allocated 1 more.
07-06 09:56:56.391: V/AndEngine(14907): org.andengine.util.adt.pool.PoolUpdateHandler$1<TouchEventRunnablePoolItem> was exhausted, with 1 item not yet recycled. Allocated 1 more.
07-06 09:56:56.462: V/AndEngine(14907): org.andengine.input.touch.TouchEvent$TouchEventPool<TouchEvent> was exhausted, with 2 item not yet recycled. Allocated 1 more.
07-06 09:56:56.465: V/AndEngine(14907): org.andengine.util.adt.pool.PoolUpdateHandler$1<TouchEventRunnablePoolItem> was exhausted, with 2 item not yet recycled. Allocated 1 more.
07-06 09:56:56.524: V/AndEngine(14907): org.andengine.input.touch.TouchEvent$TouchEventPool<TouchEvent> was exhausted, with 3 item not yet recycled. Allocated 1 more.
07-06 09:56:56.524: V/AndEngine(14907): org.andengine.util.adt.pool.PoolUpdateHandler$1<TouchEventRunnablePoolItem> was exhausted, with 3 item not yet recycled. Allocated 1 more.
07-06 09:56:56.567: V/AndEngine(14907): org.andengine.input.touch.TouchEvent$TouchEventPool<TouchEvent> was exhausted, with 4 item not yet recycled. Allocated 1 more.
07-06 09:56:56.567: V/AndEngine(14907): org.andengine.util.adt.pool.PoolUpdateHandler$1<TouchEventRunnablePoolItem> was exhausted, with 4 item not yet recycled. Allocated 1 more.
07-06 09:57:00.700: I/dalvikvm(14907): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
07-06 09:57:00.715: I/dalvikvm(14907): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
```

By the way, traces.txt does not exist. Here is where the code crashes just after executing this method:

```
private void destroyFiller(){ //Deletes filler
    if(filler[fillerNum].active){
        Log.e("destroyFiller","Destroying filler");
        filler[fillerNum].body.setActive(false);
        scene.detachChild(filler[fillerNum].sprite);
        filler[fillerNum].active=false;
        fillerCount--;
        fillersLeftText.setText("Balls left: "+Integer.toString(fillerCount));

        if(fillerCount==0)
            gameOver();
        Log.e("destroyFiller","Destroyed");
    }
}
```

And that method is called from here:

```
private ContactListener createContactListener() {
    ContactListener contactListener = new ContactListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void beginContact(Contact contact) {
            if(fillerNum>-1 && contact.getFixtureA().getBody().getUserData()!=null && contact.getFixtureB().getBody().getUserData()!=null){
                String x1 = (String) contact.getFixtureA().getBody().getUserData();
                String x2 = (String) contact.getFixtureB().getBody().getUserData();
                if((x1.equals("fill")&&!x2.equals("dest"))||(x2.equals("fill"))&&!x1.equals("dest")){ //If a filler hits a stationary
                    createStationaryFiller();
                }
                if((x1.equals("dest")&&x2.equals("fill"))||(x1.equals("fill")&&x2.equals("dest"))){ //If a destroyer hits a filler
                    destroyFiller();
                }
            }
        }
```

I can't figure out what is causing it to crash. I know the problem could be anywhere, but with 500 lines of code, I can't post it all. Anyone have any ideas or suggestions or part of the code they'd like to see?

Just checked the unfiltered LogCat and found this. Mean anything to anyone?

```
    07-06 11:21:23.696: V/WindowManager(2480): Dsptch > Window{486f5230 com.prattia.webs.testgfx5/com.prattia.webs.testgfx5.TestGFX5Activity paused=false}
07-06 11:21:23.696: V/InputDevice(2480): ID[0]=0(0) Up(1=>0)
07-06 11:21:23.696: I/PowerManagerService(2480): Ulight 3->7|0
07-06 11:21:23.794: I/DEBUG(10312): *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
07-06 11:21:23.794: I/DEBUG(10312): Build fingerprint: 'TMOUS/SGH-T959V/SGH-T959V/SGH-T959V:2.2.1/FROYO/VUVKD1:user/release-keys'
07-06 11:21:23.794: I/DEBUG(10312): pid: 17226, tid: 17256  >>> com.prattia.webs.testgfx5 <<<
07-06 11:21:23.797: I/DEBUG(10312): signal 11 (SIGSEGV), fault addr deadbaad
07-06 11:21:23.797: I/DEBUG(10312):  r0 00000000  r1 afd14921  r2 00000027  r3 00000070
07-06 11:21:23.797: I/DEBUG(10312):  r4 afd42328  r5 00000000  r6 00000000  r7 43095e58
07-06 11:21:23.797: I/DEBUG(10312):  r8 447d7b7c  r9 43095e44  10 43095e2c  fp 00000064
07-06 11:21:23.801: I/DEBUG(10312):  ip 00001730  sp 447d7a60  lr deadbaad  pc afd11f74  cpsr 60000030
07-06 11:21:23.801: I/DEBUG(10312):  d0  643a64696f72646e  d1  6472656767756265
07-06 11:21:23.801: I/DEBUG(10312):  d2  65473a3a6565726e  d3  4242414174614673
07-06 11:21:23.801: I/DEBUG(10312):  d4  6e412f73656e6967  d5  2f656e69676e4564
07-06 11:21:23.801: I/DEBUG(10312):  d6  6e69676e45646e41  d7  7363697379685065
07-06 11:21:23.801: I/DEBUG(10312):  d8  43f0000043988ca5  d9  431d03c843988ca5
07-06 11:21:23.801: I/DEBUG(10312):  d10 408ee46043cf0f5e  d11 408ee4603f800000
07-06 11:21:23.805: I/DEBUG(10312):  d12 408ee46000000000  d13 3f80000000000000
07-06 11:21:23.809: I/DEBUG(10312):  d14 0000000000000000  d15 3faebd1440000000
07-06 11:21:23.809: I/DEBUG(10312):  d16 447d777843f00000  d17 3f78b8603e39a634
07-06 11:21:23.813: I/DEBUG(10312):  d18 3f78fea6d7751d87  d19 3fd5561e206f6f3e
07-06 11:21:23.813: I/DEBUG(10312):  d20 bfc99ad1f3789aec  d21 3fc24a24221605f5
07-06 11:21:23.817: I/DEBUG(10312):  d22 bfbc737776d3846a  d23 3fb7474448cda1bc
07-06 11:21:23.817: I/DEBUG(10312):  d24 bfb3b23aa8f96cd7  d25 3fb10e7e68f17086
07-06 11:21:23.821: I/DEBUG(10312):  d26 bfaddfc803465b60  d27 3fa97c023a66406c
07-06 11:21:23.821: I/DEBUG(10312):  d28 bfa2b4442c6a6c2f  d29 3ff0000000000000
07-06 11:21:23.825: I/DEBUG(10312):  d30 0000000000000000  d31 3ff0000000000000
07-06 11:21:23.829: I/DEBUG(10312):  scr 80000012
07-06 11:21:23.977: I/DEBUG(10312):          #00  pc 00011f74  /system/lib/libc.so
07-06 11:21:23.977: I/DEBUG(10312):          #01  pc 0001921e  /system/lib/libc.so
07-06 11:21:23.981: I/DEBUG(10312):          #02  pc 00023368  /data/data/com.prattia.webs.testgfx5/lib/libandenginephysicsbox2dextension.so
07-06 11:21:23.981: I/DEBUG(10312):          #03  pc 000233d0  /data/data/com.prattia.webs.testgfx5/lib/libandenginephysicsbox2dextension.so
07-06 11:21:23.981: I/DEBUG(10312):          #04  pc 000239cc  /data/data/com.prattia.webs.testgfx5/lib/libandenginephysicsbox2dextension.so
07-06 11:21:23.981: I/DEBUG(10312):          #05  pc 000282c4  /data/data/com.prattia.webs.testgfx5/lib/libandenginephysicsbox2dextension.so
07-06 11:21:23.981: I/DEBUG(10312):          #06  pc 00014940  /data/data/com.prattia.webs.testgfx5/lib/libandenginephysicsbox2dextension.so
07-06 11:21:23.985: I/DEBUG(10312):          #07  pc 00016e34  /system/lib/libdvm.so
07-06 11:21:23.985: I/DEBUG(10312): code around pc:
07-06 11:21:23.985: I/DEBUG(10312): afd11f54 2d00682d e029d1fb b12b68db c05cf8df
07-06 11:21:23.985: I/DEBUG(10312): afd11f64 f8442001 4798000c e054f8df 26002227
07-06 11:21:23.985: I/DEBUG(10312): afd11f74 2000f88e eec2f7fb f7fc2106 f04feff8
07-06 11:21:23.985: I/DEBUG(10312): afd11f84 91035180 460aa901 96012006 f7fc9602
07-06 11:21:23.989: I/DEBUG(10312): afd11f94 a905eb7e 20024632 eb88f7fc eeaef7fb
07-06 11:21:23.989: I/DEBUG(10312): code around lr:
07-06 11:21:23.989: I/DEBUG(10312): deadba8c ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
07-06 11:21:23.989: I/DEBUG(10312): deadba9c ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
07-06 11:21:23.989: I/DEBUG(10312): deadbaac ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
07-06 11:21:23.989: I/DEBUG(10312): deadbabc ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
07-06 11:21:23.989: I/DEBUG(10312): deadbacc ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
07-06 11:21:23.989: I/DEBUG(10312): stack:
07-06 11:21:23.989: I/DEBUG(10312):     447d7a20  447d7a4c  
07-06 11:21:23.993: I/DEBUG(10312):     447d7a24  00000000  
07-06 11:21:23.993: I/DEBUG(10312):     447d7a28  afd425a0  /system/lib/libc.so
07-06 11:21:23.993: I/DEBUG(10312):     447d7a2c  afd4254c  /system/lib/libc.so
07-06 11:21:23.993: I/DEBUG(10312):     447d7a30  00000000  
07-06 11:21:23.993: I/DEBUG(10312):     447d7a34  afd1596b  /system/lib/libc.so
07-06 11:21:23.993: I/DEBUG(10312):     447d7a38  afd14921  /system/lib/libc.so
07-06 11:21:23.993: I/DEBUG(10312):     447d7a3c  afd14921  /system/lib/libc.so
07-06 11:21:23.997: I/DEBUG(10312):     447d7a40  00000070  
07-06 11:21:23.997: I/DEBUG(10312):     447d7a44  afd42328  /system/lib/libc.so
07-06 11:21:23.997: I/DEBUG(10312):     447d7a48  00000000  
07-06 11:21:23.997: I/DEBUG(10312):     447d7a4c  447d7a74  
07-06 11:21:23.997: I/DEBUG(10312):     447d7a50  43095e58  
07-06 11:21:23.997: I/DEBUG(10312):     447d7a54  afd14bc3  /system/lib/libc.so
07-06 11:21:23.997: I/DEBUG(10312):     447d7a58  df002777  
07-06 11:21:24.001: I/DEBUG(10312):     447d7a5c  e3a070ad  
07-06 11:21:24.001: I/DEBUG(10312): #00 447d7a60  00000000  
07-06 11:21:24.001: I/DEBUG(10312):     447d7a64  43095e40  
07-06 11:21:24.001: I/DEBUG(10312):     447d7a68  43095e58  
07-06 11:21:24.001: I/DEBUG(10312):     447d7a6c  afd14f29  /system/lib/libc.so
07-06 11:21:24.001: I/DEBUG(10312):     447d7a70  afd4254c  /system/lib/libc.so
07-06 11:21:24.001: I/DEBUG(10312):     447d7a74  fffffbdf  
07-06 11:21:24.004: I/DEBUG(10312):     447d7a78  0000008d  
07-06 11:21:24.004: I/DEBUG(10312):     447d7a7c  00000000  
07-06 11:21:24.004: I/DEBUG(10312):     447d7a80  43095e40  
07-06 11:21:24.004: I/DEBUG(10312):     447d7a84  afd19223  /system/lib/libc.so
07-06 11:21:24.004: I/DEBUG(10312): #01 447d7a88  0000008d  
07-06 11:21:24.004: I/DEBUG(10312):     447d7a8c  82140c18  /data/data/com.prattia.webs.testgfx5/lib/libandenginephysicsbox2dextension.so
07-06 11:21:24.004: I/DEBUG(10312):     447d7a90  82145aa8  /data/data/com.prattia.webs.testgfx5/lib/libandenginephysicsbox2dextension.so
07-06 11:21:24.004: I/DEBUG(10312):     447d7a94  8212336c  /data/data/com.prattia.webs.testgfx5/lib/libandenginephysicsbox2dextension.so
07-06 11:21:24.563: I/BootReceiver(2480): Copying /data/tombstones/tombstone_03 to DropBox (SYSTEM_TOMBSTONE)
07-06 11:21:24.590: I/DEBUG(10312): dumpstate /data/log/dumpstate_app_native.txt
07-06 11:21:24.614: I/dumpstate(17307): begin
07-06 11:21:24.622: I/dalvikvm(2480): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
07-06 11:21:24.688: D/dalvikvm(2480): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 1289 objects / 326416 bytes in 122ms
07-06 11:21:24.688: D/dalvikvm(15145): GC_EXPLICIT freed 43 objects / 1608 bytes in 826ms
07-06 11:21:24.739: I/dalvikvm(2480): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
07-06 11:21:24.747: I/dalvikvm(2604): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
07-06 11:21:24.747: I/dalvikvm(2604): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
07-06 11:21:24.754: I/dalvikvm(2610): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
07-06 11:21:24.774: I/dalvikvm(2610): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
07-06 11:21:24.813: I/dalvikvm(2613): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
07-06 11:21:24.817: I/dalvikvm(2613): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
07-06 11:21:24.821: I/dalvikvm(2621): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
07-06 11:21:24.829: I/dalvikvm(2621): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
07-06 11:21:24.833: I/dalvikvm(2630): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
07-06 11:21:24.836: I/dalvikvm(2630): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
07-06 11:21:24.840: I/dalvikvm(2636): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
07-06 11:21:24.872: I/dalvikvm(2636): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
07-06 11:21:24.879: I/dalvikvm(2691): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
07-06 11:21:24.883: I/dalvikvm(2691): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
07-06 11:21:24.915: I/dalvikvm(2744): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
07-06 11:21:24.934: I/dalvikvm(2744): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
07-06 11:21:24.942: I/dalvikvm(2767): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
07-06 11:21:24.946: I/dalvikvm(2767): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
07-06 11:21:24.954: I/dalvikvm(3339): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
07-06 11:21:24.958: I/dalvikvm(3339): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
07-06 11:21:24.965: I/dalvikvm(5990): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
07-06 11:21:24.969: I/dalvikvm(5990): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
07-06 11:21:25.004: I/dalvikvm(13294): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
07-06 11:21:25.028: I/dalvikvm(13294): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
07-06 11:21:25.028: I/dalvikvm(13691): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
07-06 11:21:25.040: I/dalvikvm(13691): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
07-06 11:21:25.051: I/dalvikvm(13737): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
07-06 11:21:25.059: I/dalvikvm(13737): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
07-06 11:21:25.122: I/dalvikvm(13930): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
07-06 11:21:25.133: I/dalvikvm(13930): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
07-06 11:21:25.137: I/dalvikvm(14722): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
07-06 11:21:25.141: I/dalvikvm(14722): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
07-06 11:21:25.172: I/dalvikvm(15145): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
07-06 11:21:25.176: I/dalvikvm(15145): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
07-06 11:21:25.180: I/dalvikvm(15266): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
07-06 11:21:25.192: I/dalvikvm(15266): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
07-06 11:21:25.196: I/dalvikvm(15684): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
07-06 11:21:25.196: I/dalvikvm(15684): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
07-06 11:21:25.200: I/dalvikvm(16472): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
07-06 11:21:25.204: I/dalvikvm(16472): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
07-06 11:21:25.208: I/dalvikvm(16506): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
07-06 11:21:25.211: I/dalvikvm(16506): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
07-06 11:21:25.239: I/dalvikvm(16523): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
07-06 11:21:25.243: I/dalvikvm(16523): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
07-06 11:21:25.274: I/dalvikvm(16649): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
07-06 11:21:25.278: I/dalvikvm(16649): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
07-06 11:21:25.278: I/dalvikvm(16695): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
07-06 11:21:25.282: I/dalvikvm(16695): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
07-06 11:21:25.286: I/dalvikvm(16701): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
07-06 11:21:25.290: I/dalvikvm(16701): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
07-06 11:21:25.290: I/dalvikvm(16711): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
07-06 11:21:25.309: I/dalvikvm(16711): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
07-06 11:21:25.321: I/dalvikvm(16761): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
07-06 11:21:25.321: I/dalvikvm(16761): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
07-06 11:21:25.325: I/dalvikvm(16767): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
07-06 11:21:25.340: I/dalvikvm(16767): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
07-06 11:21:25.340: I/dalvikvm(16782): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
07-06 11:21:25.344: I/dalvikvm(16782): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
07-06 11:21:25.348: I/dalvikvm(16791): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
07-06 11:21:25.352: I/dalvikvm(16791): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
07-06 11:21:25.352: I/dalvikvm(16797): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
07-06 11:21:25.360: I/dalvikvm(16797): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
07-06 11:21:25.364: I/dalvikvm(16817): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
07-06 11:21:25.364: I/dalvikvm(16817): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
07-06 11:21:25.368: I/dalvikvm(16892): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
07-06 11:21:25.376: I/dalvikvm(16892): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
07-06 11:21:25.379: I/dalvikvm(16926): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
07-06 11:21:25.379: I/dalvikvm(16926): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
07-06 11:21:25.383: I/dalvikvm(17226): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
07-06 11:21:25.387: I/dalvikvm(17226): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
07-06 11:21:26.758: W/PowerManagerService(2480): Timer 0x7->0x3|0x3
07-06 11:21:26.758: I/PowerManagerService(2480): Ulight 7->3|0
07-06 11:21:28.895: D/dalvikvm(13930): GC_EXPLICIT freed 995 objects / 32992 bytes in 46ms
```

Comment: `I/dalvikvm(14907): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3` Do you have any idea what is sending the signal 3?

Comment: I have absolutely no idea what that means. Is there some place I should look?

Comment: See this, maybe it helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6000742/android-andengine-problem-with-touch-events

Comment: Thanks, but I've read that post 3 or 4 times. I'm not sure I understand the problem. If it simply means don't work with a body in an IUpdateHandler, that I am doing, but I have a line of code in place that should stop it from running if the body doesn't exist.

Comment: Not sure if it is the problem, but body.setActive is one of those things that you're not supposed to do during a world step ie. in BeginContact. Google deadbaad? You could always try taking stuff out and replacing it bit by bit.

Comment: Where would the best place for me to call body.setActive()? In scene.registerUpdateHandler(new IUpdateHandler() {}? It needs to be done relatively quickly so that my other bodies don't interact with it.

Comment: Although body.setActive being called from the contact handler was something that sometimes caused a crash, the biggest error came from a different line in my code. For more information and the solution, check out this: http://www.andengine.org/forums/post36688.html#p36688

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question but I just ran into this issue.

For me, it was due to getting stuck in an infinite loop.  Technically there is no error but it prevents anything from happening.  Touch events keep getting stacked up because they cannot be handled.

Comment: Any chance you could explain your situation in a little more detail (perhaps with some code) and how your resolution applies to the question at hand?

Answer (score 0):

What this is is not really a problem. The thing is that the pool where touches are handled cannot keep up with the speeed of the touches. For example if you have an area that is touchable and you tap on it like crazy eventually you will say that the touchpool was exhausted . If you are scared with this then add a cool donw to how many times you can touch something in a certain time. Here is the cooldown code `import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

```
public class CoolDown{

    private boolean valid;
    private Timer timer;
    private long delay = 2680;
    private static CoolDown instance = null;


public static CoolDown getSharedInstance() {
    if (instance == null) {
        instance = new CoolDown();
    }
    return instance;
}

private CoolDown() {
    timer = new Timer();
    valid = true;
}

public boolean checkValidity() {
    if (valid) {
        valid = false;
        timer.schedule(new Task(), delay);
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

class Task extends TimerTask {

    public void run() {
        valid = true;
    }

}
```

}` All you need to do to implement this in on touched event is this

```
    if(!CoolDown.getSharedInstance().checkValidity())
                return false;
```

This will allow you to handle only a few events at a time so it doesnt trip that message. To change the time just change the delay which is in millis

Comment: This may or may not have anything to do with the actual crash - my reading of the logcat is that these messages precede the native crash by about 3 seconds.